# Add type variable to newtype definition

Tags: haskell, typeclass, newtype

In an exercise from Haskell Programming from First Principles it says to declare an instance of `TooMany` for the type `(Num a, TooMany a) => (a, a)` by creating a `newtype` for it first. My problem is adding a typeclass constraint to `Baz`. Is it even possible? I cannot find any other examples online.

```
class TooMany a where
  tooMany :: a -> Bool

newtype Baz = Baz (a, a) deriving (Eq, Show)

instance TooMany Baz where
  tooMany (Baz (n, _)) = n > 42
```

Comment: e.g. `instance (Num a, TooMany a) => TooMany (Baz a) where tooMany (Baz (n, m)) = n > 42 || tooMany m`.

Comment: @WillNess You also need `Ord a` but I like it. I think the writer meant to put that in the exercise, otherwise the first element can't be used for much

Comment: there are many possible definition for those two constraints, e.g. `tooMany (n+1) || tooMany m`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely need to use an argument to `Baz`:

```
newtype Baz a = Baz (a, a) deriving (Eq, Show)
        -- ^^^ --

instance (Num a, TooMany a) => TooMany (Baz a) where
   ...
```

I'm unsure about what the `Num a` is for, but I added that since you mentioned it.

Comment: I figured it needed to go in the type constructor, just couldn't figure out the syntax.